# Question on fundamental groups and homologies

Tags: algebraic-topology

I am stuck on the following qualifying Exam question.  I was wondering if there was an easy way of doing such a problem.  Thank you in advance.

Let $V_1 \subset \mathbb{R}^4$, $V_2, \subset \mathbb{R}^4$ be linear subspaces, where the dimension of $V_j$ is $j$, $j = 1, 2$.  Assume that $V_1 \subsetneq V_2$, and let $X = \mathbb{R}^4\backslash (V_1 \cup V_2).$  Calculate the fundamental group and homology groups of $X$.

Comment: Did you mean to write $V_1 \not\subset V_2$ where you have $V_1 \subsetneq V_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I am going to assume that you meant $V_1\cap V_2=0$.*

Notice that $\mathbb R^4-V_1\cup V_2$ deformation retracts to its intersection with the unit sphere $S^3\subseteq\mathbb R^4$; this is easy to see. Call this intersection $X$: it is the complement in $S^3$ of the union of a pair of antipodal points and an maximal circle (which is a subset homeorphic to $S^2$)

Now do stereographic projection from one of those two antipodal points, let's cay $p$: this gives a map $\phi:S^3-\{p\}\to\mathbb R^3$ which is an homemorphism, which we can restrict to an homeo $X\to\phi(X)\subseteq\mathbb R^3$. The image under $\phi$ of the union of the set $\{-p\}$ and the circle is a point and a circle, so $\phi(X)$ is the complement in $\mathbb R^3$ of a point union a circle.

Now: can you compute the fundamental group and the homology of your space?